# Nested AND/OR Statement in a Validation Rule on the Case Object

Tags: formula, case, validation-rule, nested

I've tried following other resources, but decided to share this one to see if anyone could help me get the syntax correct:
I need to display an Error message on the Case Record when someone tries to change the Case status to "Closed" IF the following criteria are TRUE:
Project_Checklist_Complete__c = False (meaning they should check this box prior to closing)
AND only If Type is one of these two choices from the same type picklist - Type = Installation/System Setup Or Type = De-installation

Here is my current Formula that is not working:

```
AND
(
    ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed"),
    Project_Checklist_Complete__c = False,
    OR(
        ISPICKVAL(Type, "De-installation")
        ISPICKVAL(Type, "Installation/System Setup")
    )
)
```

Any help would be appreciated to get the syntax in the right order. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot a comma in the OR function. Each parameter of a function needs a comma between them.

```
AND
(
  ISPICKVAL(Status, "Closed"),
  NOT(Project_Checklist_Complete__c),
  OR(
    ISPICKVAL(Type, "De-installation"),
    ISPICKVAL(Type, "Installation/System Setup")
  )
)
```

Some notes:

- A Boolean is already true or false, so you can just use NOT for false, or the field itself for true.
- It helps makes things more obvious if you indent and line break your formula. This is demonstrated above.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly.

Comment: @PatrickFuller Of course, glad to help!